# One-to-one correspondence list of dictionaries based on two nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have two nested lists:

```
a = [[0, 1],[1, 0],[2, 0]]
b = [[2, 1],[1, 3],[8, 1]]
```

I want to have a list of dictionaries such that each inner element of list `a` (as key) corresponds to it's inner element of list `b` (as value).

Here's my desired output:
`[{0:2,1:1},{1:1,0:3},{2:8,0:1}]`

I've tried:

```
  ls = []
  for i in a:
    for j in b:
        ls.append({k:v for k,v in zip(i, j)})
  print(ls)
```

But it gives me all the possible combinations which I don't want. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a list comprehension and `zip`.

```
>>> a = [[0, 1],[1, 0],[2, 0]]
>>> b = [[2, 1],[1, 3],[8, 1]]
>>> [dict(zip(i, j)) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
[{0: 2, 1: 1}, {1: 1, 0: 3}, {2: 8, 0: 1}]
```